# How Can I Create Materialize Css Inputs Design & Features from Scratch Without Using Materialize Css?

Tags: css, materialize

How can I to create Materialize CSS inputs with the Special features of it, like Placeholders and Icons inside inputs? I want to find a way to create it without using materialize CSS because I am using another CSS framework and I don't want to use more than one framework preventing errors of multiplying frameworks?

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_form.asp

Answer (score 0):

Try checking out the materialiseCSS CSS file, and also the corresponding CSS codes for forms/placeholders or any HTML tag, then attach the needed codes to your normal CSS file using either an id or class